Tobit estimation on panel data in combination with an IV approach in R?
I have panel data (country by year) and my dependent variable is left-censored (many countries have zero values, other countries have very large numbers). So, I think that I should implement a Tobit model on panel data. Additionally, I suspect reverse causality and I also need to implement an IV approach at the same time. How can I do this in R? And how can I be sure that my standard errors are correctly calculated?
Ideally, I would be able to implement this using
a. fixed effects,
b. pooling,
c. random effects and
d. first-differences.
# Second- and first-stage IV regression
fixed1_iv_2sls_IMP <- ivreg(Y ~ X + W + factor(country) + 
                            factor(year) |  Z + W + 
                            factor(country) + factor(year),
                  data = data)

# Extract residuals
data$res_fixed1_iv_2sls_IMP <- residuals(fixed1_iv_2sls_IMP)

# Tobit regression on residuals
tobit_model <- censReg(res_fixed1_iv_2sls_IMP ~ X + W + 
                       factor(country) + factor(year),
                       left = 0, right = 100, data = data)

# Summary of Tobit model
summary(tobit_model)

# HAC standard errors
fixed1_iv_2sls_IMP_se <- coeftest(fixed1_iv_2sls_IMP, 
               vcov = vcovHC(fixed1_iv_2sls_IMP, type = "HC3"))[, 2]

